# Text after the end of a nested list doesn't align properly

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

For example, this

```
1. first item
2. second item
    - first subitem
    - second subitem
   more info about the 2nd item
3. third item
```

produces this

[image]

How do I get "more info about the 2nd item" to appear where it does in the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following places "more info" as an independant paragraph inside the second subitem bullet point, in `pandoc` markdown.

```
1. first item
2. second item
    - first subitem
    - second subitem

        more info about the 2nd item

3. third item
```

Output:

```
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>first item</li>
<li>second item
<ul>
<li>first subitem</li>
<li><p>second subitem</p>
<p>more info about the 2nd item</p></li>
</ul></li>
<li>third item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a nasty problem which I also cannot seem to solve in an elegant way. However, for compilation to HTML there is a simple workaround: place a `</ul>` or `</ol>` tag after the last item of your nested list.

```
1. first item
2. second item
    - first subitem
    - second subitem</ul>
   more info about the 2nd item
3. third item
```

This will trigger the HTML to end the - in this case unordered - nested list before Markdown instructs it to. Luckily, this doesn't break your layout at all, *as long as you are mixing unordered (`<ul>`) and ordered (`<ol>`) lists.* If your nested list is of the same type as its parent this *will* break your layout*.

If so desired, you can also place a `<br>` element before the first line that does not belong to the nested list anymore, which I find to produce a more visually appealing layout.